# Short way to write a long case statement

Tags: ruby, case-statement

I have an extremely long case statement:

```
def gather_intel
  case OPTIONS[:type]
    when /osha/
      FORMAT.info('Creating OSHA Regional email..')
      EMAILS.osha_reg
    when /pend/
      FORMAT.info('Creating 6 day hold pending email..')
      EMAILS.pend
    when /60/
      FORMAT.info('Creating 60 day hold account deletion email..')
      EMAILS.sixty_day
    when /generic/
      FORMAT.info('Creating generic email..')
      EMAILS.generic
    when /resolve/
      FORMAT.info('Creating resolution ticket..')
      EMAILS.resolve
    when /esc/
      FORMAT.info('Creating escalation ticket..')
      EMAILS.assign
    when /pii/
      FORMAT.info('Creating request to remove personal info..')
      EMAILS.remove_pii
    when /vip/
      FORMAT.info('Creating VIP user email..')
      EMAILS.vip_user
    when /inop/
      FORMAT.info('Creating INOP user email..')
      EMAILS.in_op_user
    when /dev/
      if OPTIONS[:type].to_s.include?('dev=unlock')
        message = 'unlock'
      else
        message = 'password reset'
      end
      FORMAT.info("Creating dev account #{message} email")
      EMAILS.dev_account(OPTIONS[:type])
    else
      raise ERROR
  end
end
```

This `case statement` works however I will be unable to show you the rest of the code due to the project sensitivity and material. My question is, is there an easier more readable way to write this `case statement`, or a shorter way to write it?

Comment: There is no need for your example to be so long. You could pair it down to just a few clauses without changing the substance of the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just copied the entire method over to SO, just to be sure. Didn't want someone to assume I didn't do anything.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming `info` in `FORMAT.info('Creating INOP user email..')` is a method?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's actually a class, inside of a module, inside of another file. Lol. I can probably edit this to make it actually run able.

Comment: I think the best thing to do is just separate it into separate methods. You would still have one long case statement but each case just forwards to a separate method.

Comment: This is *perfect* candidate for the Replace Conditional With Polymorphism Refactoring. Hint: what does `foo.bar` do? It switches on the type of `foo` and executes different `bar`s depending on the type of `foo`. What does your `case` expression do? It switches on some type and executes different code depending on the type. Heck, the value you are switching on is even *called* `:type`!!! You have basically re-implemented method lookup, badly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Rather than giving OP a hard time, why not post an answer that will actually help them solve their problem?

Comment: @JohnDoeYo The fact that you're using a regular expression for each `when` is a little troubling. Do you really need to match *any* string that contains e.g. "osha", or is there a way you can transform the value of `OPTIONS[:type]` first to "normalize" it so you can do a simple equality match? That would simplify things a lot.

Comment: @Jordan It has to match that exact information, how the program is run, is a flag is given to the call `-t osha` and if that flag finds `osha` it sends it to the correct method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand some of the details of the question, but here's a general approach you might take. I've assumed that `:info` and the values of `:email` in the hash below are names of methods. (I understand that assumption is incorrect.) The following may have errors, considering that I have no means of testing it.

```
DATA = [[/osha/,    'Creating OSHA Regional email..',                :osha_reg],
        [/pend/,    'Creating 6 day hold pending email..',           :pend],
        [/60/,      'Creating 60 day hold account deletion email..', :sixty_day],
        [/generic/, 'Creating generic email..',                      :generic],
        [/resolve/, 'Creating resolution ticket..',                  :resolve],
        [/esc/,     'Creating escalation ticket..',                  :assign],
        [/pii/,     'Creating request to remove personal info..',    :remove_pii],
        [/vip/,     'Creating VIP user email..',                     :vip_user],
        [/inop/,    'Creating INOP user email..',                    :in_op_user]]

def gather_intel
  type = OPTIONS[:type]
  regex, msg, email = DATA.find { |r,*_| type =~ r }
  if regex
    FORMAT.send :info, msg
    EMAILS.send email
  elsif type =~ /dev/ 
    message = type.to_s.include?('dev=unlock') ? 'unlock' : 'password reset'
    FORMAT.info("Creating dev account #{message} email")
    EMAILS.dev_account(type)
  else
    raise ERROR
  end
end
```